# Rotate UIImage in drawRect

Tags: iphone, uiimage, rotation

I have the following code that displays an image when the drawRect is called.

```
  UIImage *sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];    


CGRect rect = CGRectMake(12.5, 12.5, 
                         sourceImage.size.width, 
                         sourceImage.size.height);

[sourceImage drawInRect:rect];
```

How can I get this rotated by a number of degrees before it gets drawn, everything I read needs it in a ImageView which seems heavy in a drawRect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];
imageView.image = image;
[self addSubview:imageView];
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 1.0 / 180.0 * 3.14 );
[imageView setTransform:rotate];
```

Comment: Only comments: probably better to use M_PI rather than 3.14, for clarity if nothing else, and don't forget that 'frame' shouldn't be used if you've set a transform, which also seems often to prevent correct behaviour upon interface orientation changes.

Comment: I get the point on the M_PI but not the frame. How would that relate to my code?

Answer (score 4):

Rotating (or any other transformation done by a transformation matrix) is not "heavy". All the transforms basically are simple multiplications of a vector and a small matrix (see [Apple's Quartz 2D documentation for the math](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD))

Use `CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians);` before you draw the image with `[sourceImage drawInRect:rect];`. If you need to rotate the image around another point, translate with `CGContextTranslateCTM` first.